# OpenCV image stitching error IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I have used the iOS openCV library for stitching images to create my panoramic app. However, if I try to use more than 2 images I get the following error.

> Removed some images, because can't match them or there are too similar
>   images. Try to decrease --match_conf value and/or check if you're
>   stitching duplicates.

Anybody know what the issue is and how to avoid this? I have used the related images taken from my camera.

Comment: You may solve it by removing some images. Also, you could try to decrease match_conf value, and check your images for duplicates...

Comment: the images that i hav used are not duplicates and where can i find this match_conf value?